# Why do all my CMakelist.txt files in different folders get overwritten everytime I edit any of the copies?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, cmake-language

I have a folder /home/ros/codes. Inside it, I have datewise folders where I have a CMakeLists.txt file and a *build* folder inside which I run cmake.. and make command.

Recently, I observed if I edit any CMakelists.txt file from any of this group of folders, the edits get automatically overwritten in all others files. Even if I have renamed the other file to -say- CMakelists(copy).txt , still the changes are being reflected.
I can see these are locked files.So I am using sudo gedit to edit them.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it further?

Comment: Are all the CMakeLists.txt files then identical? Could they be symlinks? Can you do `ls -la` of some of the files to see?

Comment: Yes, identical. 
I didn't know what a symlink is and after doing ls -la, all the files output "lrwxrwxrwx 1 nvidian nvidian 50 Oct <date_of_creation> <time_of_creation> -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"

So, they could be symlinks right?

Comment: All right, the `-> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` tells you that they are indeed symlinks. This means you actually only have one file, toplevel.cmake, and all the rest are just shortcuts to that file.